# iTerm2: Notice about PHP7.1

Tags: terminal, homebrew, iterm, php

Every time I open a new iTerm2 window is shown the following warning:

`Warning: Use php@7.1 instead of deprecated homebrew/php/php71`

Anyone can help me out please?

I've uninstalled PHP, and installed again, and the problem remains.

I've also checked this [HomeBrew PHP issue](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-php/issues/4825) but after I run:

```
brew untap homebrew/php
```

I get the following:

```
Error: No available formula with the name "homebrew/php/php71"
Please tap it and then try again: brew tap homebrew/php
```

After I run the last command recommended I get again the initial warning.

I have macOS High Sierra 10.13.3.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Check your shell config files (i.e. `.bashrc`, `.zshrc`, etc.) Chances are, somewhere in there you're calling `$(brew --prefix homebrew/php/php71)`, probably as part of a `PATH` setting. When you installed `php` via `brew`, it provided instructions for setting the path that would have included the above line.

I was seeing the exact same message, and changing this line solved the issue for me. You can change it to `$(brew --prefix php@7.1)` if you still need it.

Comment: This was it in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is due to using Homebrew for iterm2. Can you just load and install iterm2 from its home page [here](https://iterm2.com). If you uninstall iterm2 and load it from home page it should work fine. I say this because I installed iterm2 from its home page and it works fine.

Comment: Thanks. I've tried that and the problem remains. Also they have the same version: 3.1.5.